# Answered questions showing up in unanswered tab - why?

Tags: discussion

New on here, have been browsing unanswered questions in the websphere-mq tag. I get to around page 4/5 of the list of unanswered questions and then questions which say they do have answers start showing up. The tab at the top still suggests I am viewing unanswered questions though. What is the reason for this?

I infer a question has an answer from the number at the left of the title saying the number of answers. On the first three pages they always says 0 answers next to the post title.

Comment: Unanswered != no answers. Unanswered means: no *upvoted or accepted* answers.

Comment: FYI - I didn't think that article was relevant to me as I had not seen the Unanswered tab in two places. Might require further editing to be useful to new people? The comment that Unanswered is not the same as no answers was the fact I was missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stack Exchange definition of "unanswered" is

> a question that has no **upvoted** answers.

Therefore a question that has several zero (or negatively) scored answers it will appear in this list.

If you want truly unanswered questions then you need to go here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers

Comment: Thank you for the link, however, when I add the tag to it, it seems to get rid of the tab. How would I see the "no answers" questions for a particular tag, say 'websphere-mq'?

Comment: @MoragHughson http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/websphere-mq/?tab=noanswers is what you want in that case.

Comment: Confuses me every single time. Would make more sense to either distinguish between *unanswered* and *unaccepted* (and offer both tabs) or let us pick from a number of queries or even let us customize our own, configurable from the account settings. I bet you if that was possible, SE might suddenly find out other useful queries they never thought of.